# Making a chat room in Rails hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying to make a pretty basic chat room in rails. I'd love to use juggernaut/node.js but heroku doesn't currently support it. I'm thinking I should just use the heroku addon "pusher." Does anyone recommend this solution or any other alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A real-time chat web app by Tom Arnfeld:
http://pusher-chat.heroku.com/

The code behind it:
https://github.com/tarnfeld/PusherChat-Rails

Hope that sets you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks Kate! I'll definitely look into this!

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you to watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

It is a more Evented I/O way.

some successful implement in heroku , but it is advised to host it own self , according to this 
http://groups.google.com/group/faye-users/browse_thread/thread/ade91b737e495bdf